# Wires combination configurations

Tags: configuration, combinations, probability, compatibility

I need to create macro Excel generating all possible combinations of wires.

I have the following list of wires each one is called by its options (OP1, OP2,...)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7FGo.png)

the options have a table of compatibility, "1" for options who can came together and "0" for non compatible ones.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlHdu.png)

I have an example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6pA6.png)

if you can see config_1 has all wires without wires called by OPtions:L126, L115, L116, L122, L123, L124
those Options are incompatible with option L125.

I'm just trying manually and its impossible